# how to activate/passivate docker containers in aws

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I have a stateful app running under Tomcat with a proprietary database. I have successfully dockerized it on my machine and it is easy to run a single instance of it on AWS. The database is not very big (under a gig) and every customer will want their own version of it. So, our plan is that each customer essentially gets his own copy of the system. Each customer will have a small number of users of the system (often 1, maybe 10) and usually use it for just a few hours per week.

When we get a new customer XYZ, we'll create a new Docker container for their system. They will go to "XYZ.mycompany.com" and log in to the system. We should then spin up the container for them. Eventually they will log out or time out. Then we should passivate the container.

So, what part of AWS would handle the activation/passivation of the Docker containers?  This is different from the usual AWS architecture where the containers are stateless.  I can imagine a http front end (proxy?) that takes http requests and decides which container they go to, starting up the container if necessary.   Is there a standard package I could use for this, or do I have to write one?

Answer (score 0):

> passivation

I don't even think that's a word. :P  Neither Docker nor AWS have that concept.

I can think of several simple ways to solve your problem, but you're not going to like them.

1) Run a Reserved Instance micro instance for each customer. Yes, this is "expensive", but that's the architecture you assumed when you wrote your software. Don't blame me or the cloud.  You have to architect for the cloud if you want the benefits.

Also, don't dismiss this as a solution -- often times, [you have to do things that don't scale](http://paulgraham.com/ds.html) to get started. You are spending money to validate your business model. Once you have customers, you can decide to spend your time saving money instead of adding features. But if the customers never show up, then you don't need to waste your time on the software.

2) Fix your software to be multi-tenant. (Step one, get rid of your custom database. There are thousands of open-source and hosted databases out there, written by thousands of experts. No offense, but it's unlikely that your code is better than all of theirs.)  Pretty much every SaaS business starts with multi-tenant software as a first-class requirement.

Now, the problem is simple. Stateless app servers (don't need 1 per customer anymore, but 1 per every 1000 users) and a stateful database layer. As you grow, there are lots of established techniques to grow your database. (Master-Master, Slave Reads, Sharding, break up your app into microservices with their own smaller databases)

3) Write a wrapper around your software that spins up and down docker containers, then routes to the running container.  Every container should store it's data on the host filesystem under `/somewhere/COMPANYNAME/` (using `-v` flag) so data is not lost when the container is not running.

If you want robustness, you should put `/somewhere` on EFS. That will let you run docker containers on multiple hosts.  The "routing" layer that will spin up/down containers and route requests will be **very tricky** to write (race conditions abound). You might even be able to hide the spin up/down latency by giving them a "login" screen while you spin up the container.

It *could* work. But you have to decide: Is your value to your customers in your custom DB and your custom routing layer? Or is it in what the software actually does, and therefore it is better to use a commodity routing layer (ELB) and commodity database (RDS, Dynamo, or any other random well-tested multi-user DB you can think of)?

P.S. You might be able to re-use parts of https://sandstorm.io/